# How can I SUMIFS where criteria is a set of numbers from a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, criteria, sumifs

I have an Excel file that looks like this:

```
ZONES             Count                          Area 1 = (SUM OF ZONE COUNT)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                 100                            1
2                 50                             2
3                 110                            5
4                 90                             7
5                 40                             
6                 10                             
7                 0                              
8                 80
```

What I need to do is make (SUM OF ZONE COUNT) say `190` since 100+40+50+0 = 190.  I've tried:

```
=SUMIFS(B3:B10, A3:A10, C3)
```

And it will return `100`. When I try:

```
=SUMIFS(B3:B10, A3:A10, "="&C3:C6)
```

It returns `0`.

I need to set the criteria to be a range instead of an individual cell.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this version

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B3:B10,A3:A10,C3:C6))`

because the criteria range is four cells the SUMIFS function will return an "array" of four values - SUMPRODUCT is used to sum those four values

You can also use SUM but the formula needs to be "array entered", i.e.

`=SUM(SUMIFS(B3:B10,A3:A10,C3:C6))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I played around with sumproduct and sumifs, but not both together!  You're a life saver!